# Insert the next recurring charge date in custom table when user purchase a product?

Tags: 7, ubercart

My site have a `subscriber role` that have some special permissions. User has to purchase the role. I used `ubercart` module for this.

I added a `feature` to assign role on purchase of subscription. Subscription can be for 1 week, 1 month or 1 year. User can cancel own recurring charge. `Uc_role` module manages the assign and remove role of user. It handles the next date of recurring. But `uc_role` not manages the past date.

My question is that I want to show the user who purchase a subscription in past. Is there any hook or something so I can work on it?

Comment: So, uc_role has only scheduler and you need a log, right? On each change of this role, you need to save "$username got $rolename at 2034-11-27" and alike?

Comment: @Mołot yes yes.. I need same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this just by adding my custom code `db_insert()` in `uc_role.module` file in `uc_role_grant` and `uc_role_renew` function.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar although I don't think it's the best way.

I created a rule that is triggered with the event I wanted and then added an action which was custom php. Then use drupal db api to make the update or insert in the table.

https://drupal.org/project/rules
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7

Comment: I am thinking similar but how can I get the date in php code?

Comment: What is the date you want to store? I'm not familiar with uc_role

Comment: Next recurring date and also update automatically when recurring happen.

Comment: so the next recurring date would be now + 12months?
You would need to make sure the uid is the primary key in your table and then look into an sql statement like "INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY" where you try and insert uid and the date if uid exists it updates the date.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html